# Does this mean the patch took?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

Before starting up VtMB again I downloaded and installed an unofficial patch hoping to get the sewer shortcut and avoid those troublesome pipes. The gameplay screen *says* Unofficial Patch 10.6 but my old pre-patch saves still remain.

Did the patch take? Please I ***really*** need to know if I've come this far for nothing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your saves don't automatically disappear when you install the patch, **but** you should probably not try to play them. Even if this works initially, you may encounter game-breaking bugs.  For example, imagine not being able to finish the game due to a bug that makes the final boss invulnerable.

However, having replayed Bloodlines a few times, I can testify that replaying an episode is much, much faster than playing it for the first time. So, just play till the sewers part, it really won't take you too long.